Movie about a dying man trying to save a Sequoia park
Help me identify old movie about a man, who was dying of a lung disease and he fights to save a sequoia park (I can't remember from what).
It is an old movie 80s or before.

Possibly Guardian of the Wilderness (AKA Mountain Man) from 1976 about the life of Galen Clark. From the TVGuide synopsis:

Clark, a man who helped pass legislation to save the Sequoia Forest of Yosemite in the 1860s... is a miner who in his later years contracts black lung disease. He sets out for the wilderness and fresh air and encounters Dehner, a naturalist, who joins him. Pyle finds a great forest of sequoias and settles down in a nearby valley, where he builds a cabin. Lumber companies try to come in and cut down the huge trees, but Pyle and Dehner fight them off.

